# List won't populate next item unless an action item is tapped to change the state

Tags: ios, angular

I have a small component that I am trying to pass some data into. The component iterates through the data and displays a list of items. This works fine on desktop and from what I understand android mobile as well. It does not work with iOS. I have a link to show the behavior here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/iqs3xn/list_doesnt_load_until_i_tap_screen_ios/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

In the video you'll see how I can't get the next item in the list to appear, unless I click on something that would change the behavior inside the current route. I've never encountered this before. I did recently upgrade from angular 8 to 10.

Here is the home component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { CardService } from '../services/card.service';
import { Observable, combineLatest, Subject, } from 'rxjs';
import { DeckService } from '../services/deck.service';
import { RecentDeck } from '../core/models/recent-deck.model';
import { TrendingCard } from '../core/models/trending-card.model';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  protected ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  
  trendingCards: any;
  trendingLeaders:  any;
  recentDecks: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { } 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.trendingCards = this.route.snapshot.data['trendingCards'];
    this.recentDecks = this.route.snapshot.data['recentDecks'];
    this.trendingLeaders = this.route.snapshot.data['trendingLeaders'];
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML for the home component:

```
<main class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row mt-3'>
        <section class='col col-md-4' *ngIf="recentDecks; else loading">
            <app-recent-decks [recentDecks]="recentDecks.decks"></app-recent-decks>
        </section>
        <section class='col col-md-4' *ngIf="trendingLeaders; else loadingLeaders">
            <app-trending-leaders [trendingLeaders]="trendingLeaders" ></app-trending-leaders>
        </section>
        <section class='col col-md-4'  *ngIf="trendingCards; else loadingCards">
            <app-trending-cards [trendingCards]="trendingCards"></app-trending-cards>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
<ng-template #loading>
    <section class='col col-md-4'>
        <app-loading title="Recent Decks"></app-loading>
    </section>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #loadingLeaders>
    <section class='col col-md-4'>
        <app-loading title="Trending Leaders"></app-loading>
    </section>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #loadingCards>
    <section class='col col-md-4'>
        <app-loading title="Trending Cards"></app-loading>
    </section>
</ng-template>
```

The component that is providing all of the issues is `app-recent-decks`. Here is the code for that component as well:

**recent-decks.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RecentDeck } from '../../../../core/models/recent-deck.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recent-decks',
  templateUrl: './recent-decks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recent-decks.component.scss']
})
export class RecentDecksComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() recentDecks: Array<any>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

**recent-decks.component.html**

```
<div class='card trending-list'>
    <div class='card-header'>
        <h3>Community Decks</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='card-body p-0'>
        <ul class='list-group' *ngIf="recentDecks">
            <a [routerLink]="['/deck/view', d.id]" class='list-group-item list-group-item-action py-0' *ngFor="let d of recentDecks;">
                <div class="float-left w-100 trending-list-info">
                    <div class='leader-stats ellipsis'><strong>{{d.title}}</strong>
                    <br><small>Posted By: {{d.username}} on {{d.submitDate | date}}</small></div>
                </div>
                <img src="{{d.leader.imageUrl[0]}}"/>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My main question is, what is causing this behavior to happen, and what can I do to prevent it in the future?

NOTES: There is no error output for debugging that is readable or helpful.